# How to ask the Apple Review team to review an app more quickly than usual?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I uploaded a new application to iTunes connect on last Thursday. Client wants to the app Live on coming Friday. He wants to request the Apple App Store Review team to review the app as soon as possible. How can we do this in iTunes Connect?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Expedited App Review**

> Expedite iOS app review to less than 24 hours

you can submit your app in `Expedited App Review`, apple release your app in max 24 hours.but you can submit your app in only in two ways.

**Urgent Bug Fix**

> If you've submitted an update to fix a critical bug in your app on the App Store and you are requesting an expedited review, be sure to include the steps to reproduce the bug on the current version of your app

**Time-Sensitive Event**

> For apps associated with an event, When submitting your request, it's important to include the event, date of the event, and your app's association with the event.

some additional Information see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124124/expedite-ios-app-review-to-less-than-24-hours)

---

[**Steps to implement the Expedited App Review**](https://mobileroadie.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200091766-Requesting-Expedited-App-Review-on-iTunes)

**Step-1**

- Login to `iTunes Connect` using your `iOS Developer Account credentials`
- Scroll to the bottom of the `iTunes Connect webpage` and click `Contact Us`

[image]

**Step-2**

- Select `App Review`, `App Store Review`, and `Request Expedited Review`, then select `Request an Expedited App Review`.

  [image]

**Step-3**

- Fill in the requested information and click `Submit` to send your request to Apple! They will review and respond to the request and let you know if they are able to expedite the review of your app!.

Comment: Thank you Anbu. I will do the same. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I accepted your answer and upvoted :). Thanks again :)