# How to remove mistakenly added small version number on iTunes?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Currently my app which is ready for sale had version 3.0. I was ready to push another app. So I clicked on this app, clicked on add new version/platform. and mistakenly wrote 1.0 as version there.
this resulted in this:

[image]

1. Issue is, I am not able to delete this "1" version (help me here),
2. If I upload build for for this, it will take time in review process, and ultimately, Apple will reject it and again lot of time will be wasted.
3. How to get a response from Apple sooner?

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750742/how-to-approach-apple-review-team-to-review-the-app-asap/35750869#35750869

Comment: Feels like contacting/calling [Apple developer support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) may be a good thing to start with, at least in parallel with asking here if you have a tight deadline.

Comment: Yes i know about the expedite review. but isn't it only available after we  have submitted build for review.?
My main question is , i just want to delete this new version "prepare for submission", and make another version (3.1) instead of 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Select the build and scroll to "General App Information", you can change it there.

2) Anytime you submit an update it will go through the review process.

3) You can request an expedited review under the Help > Contact Us menu, or [This form.](https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=expedite)

Comment: Sorry, looks like i am in a hurry and ignored the most easiest way.
thanks a lot.