# Can I have same application of different build version in "Ready For Sale" state but not released to app store?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Am having some clarification on submitting the app in the app store

1. I submitted the app for review in the app store with platform version 3.0 and build version 1.0.1
2. While submitting the app for review i checked "Manually Release this version" option.
3. Now my app got approved in the app store and its in the state "Ready For Sale" but not yet released to the app store.
4. Now we have fixed critical bug on our app and i want to submit the app for review and want to release new build in the app store instead of the old version(platform version 3.0 and build version 3.0.1) which is in ready for sale state but not yet released

Can I submit the new build (platform version 3.0 and build version 3.0.2) for review in app store by already having another build in "Ready for sale" state?

If yes is the answer for the above question then once our app(platform version 3.0 and build version 3.0.2) get approved, can i release this new build to the app store instead of the old version(platform version 3.0 and build version 3.0.1) which is in already ready for sale state but not yet released?

Thanks and appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your **Question -1**

> Can I submit the new build (platform version 3.0 and build version 3.0.2) for review in app store by already having another build in "Ready for sale" state?

**Answer**

> ya you can submit ,in here you need to mention the changes for this particular version.

for your **Question -2**

> can i release this new build to the app store instead of the old version(platform version 3.0 and build version 3.0.1)

**Answer**

> you **can't submit** ,before ready for sale we can do anything in itunes connect, but once its comes on ready for sale , we need to upload currentbuildNo + additionSomething.

additional [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750742/how-to-approach-apple-review-team-to-review-the-app-asap) for release the app in with in the day.

Comment: So, I need to release the old build(platform version 3.0 and build version 3.0.1) which is in ready for sale state but not released to the app store in order to release new build (platform version 3.0 and build version 3.0.2) to app store?Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @SDK - you can directly release **3.0.2** in app store it only shows ** 3.0** , so there is no problem